# Magento2: How to show error message if customer is LoggedIn?

Tags: magento2.2, customer-account

I have created custom form and create custom controller if customer is LoggedIn, then if anyone try to do registration then it requires to show the error message, how can i do that?

Comment: @sumit if you know please let me know

Comment: can you add your code here what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This**

```
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

/**
 * Class Index
 */
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context
 * @param Customer
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    Session $customerSession,
) {
    $this->customerSession   = $customerSession;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
public function execute()
{
            if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
                $this->messageManager->addWarning('User is loggedIn');
                return $resultRedirect;
            }
        } else {
            $this->messageManager->addWarning('User Not loggedIn');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
}

}
```

**Other Funtions in Message Manager**

1. addWarning
2. addSucces
3. addError